# Remove £ sign from Varchar price then add a decimal to it - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the following code, price is a varchar which will hold a string such as £10.95
How do I remove the £ sign, change it to a decimal, add the decimal value @currentprice to it and SET it back as a varchar with the £ sign back in it? Not sure where to start with this. I know I should have stored price as a decimal originally but I was just learning and it would mean a huge re-write now. Any suggestions for getting this to work?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [UpdateOrderSentForBar]
@orderID   uniqueidentifier,
@tableNo varchar(255),
@currentprice decimal

AS
BEGIN

IF (SELECT orderStatus FROM tblOrders WHERE orderID=@orderID)='SentForKitchen'
BEGIN

IF (Select top 1 stallMessage From tblOrders WHERE tblNo = @tableNo AND orderStatus != 'Completed' AND orderID != @orderID) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
UPDATE tblOrders
SET stallMessage = stallMessage + (Select top 1 stallMessage From tblOrders WHERE tblNo = @tableNo AND orderStatus!='Completed' AND orderID !=@orderID), price = (select '£' + cast(@currentprice + cast(replace(price,'£','') as decimal(9,2)) as varchar))

WHERE orderID=@orderID
END
```

I've also tried another suggestion below like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [UpdateOrderSentForBar]
@orderID   uniqueidentifier,
@tableNo varchar(255),
@currentprice decimal

AS
BEGIN   

DECLARE @totalprice DECIMAL(18,5)

SELECT @totalprice = CAST(REPLACE(price, '£', '') AS  DECIMAL(18,2)) + @currentprice FROM tblOrders WHERE orderID=@orderID
SELECT FORMAT(@totalprice, 'C', 'en-gb')

IF (SELECT orderStatus FROM tblOrders WHERE orderID=@orderID)='SentForKitchen'
BEGIN

IF (Select top 1 stallMessage From tblOrders WHERE tblNo = @tableNo AND orderStatus != 'Completed' AND orderID != @orderID) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
UPDATE tblOrders
SET stallMessage = stallMessage + (Select top 1 stallMessage From tblOrders WHERE tblNo = @tableNo AND orderStatus!='Completed' AND orderID !=@orderID), price = @totalprice

WHERE orderID=@orderID
END
```

Comment: Do it right and change the schema so that prices aren't stored as strings with currency symbols but numbers (and the currency in *another* column, if multi currency capability is needed) in the first place.

Comment: Yes I should have done this in the beginning but as I say, I was learning and to change all the code now would be a nightmare.. There's a lot! I understand my mistake but was wondering if there was a way to do this with a quick fix here until I am ready to do a complete website update when I get time.

Comment: @markdavies do you want to store back with actual value or rounded back to 2 decimals?

Comment: @SelvaS needs to be rounded back to 2 decimals. It will always be just 2 money values added together.

Comment: Check out the `replace` and `try_cast` functions.

Comment: In fact what is wrong with your replace and case? You say you are way off... but that works right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inline, you're on the right track,

```
select '£' + cast(@currentprice + cast(replace(pricetoadd,'£','') as decimal(9,2)) as varchar)
```

I would highly recommend never storing prices as strings, let alone with a currency symbol, that is the job of the presentation layer.

Also note I've chosen decimal (9,2) - that should suffice for all reasonable monetary values, and should really be the data type in the database.

Edit

In the context of your update it would be something like

```
update o set
    o.stallMessage = o.stallMessage + (
        Select top 1 stallMessage
        From tblOrders
        where tblNo = @tableNo AND orderStatus!='Completed' AND orderID !=@orderID
    ),
    o.price='£' + cast(@currentprice + cast(replace(o.price,'£','') as decimal(9,2)) as varchar)
from tblorders o
where o.orderID=@orderID
```

*(untested)*

Comment: I've edited my original answer to incorporate this. Have I got it in the correct place? I still get: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: @markdavies I've edited above to refactor your update, I'm unable to test it but hopefully you can follow.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, but same error with that code. I can see what you're trying to do but it doesn't like it for some reason.

Comment: Still same error when I tried your update

Comment: Does this work for you in isolation?

`declare @price varchar(10)='£12.34', @currentprice decimal(9,2)=2.56;
select @price= '£' + cast(@currentprice + cast(replace(@price,'£','') as decimal(9,2)) as varchar);
select @price`

Comment: Yes it did @sTTu

Comment: Would need to see the data you are using to diagnose further, if you can post the actual table schema and sample data.

Comment: What's the best way to post that? Sorry for being such an amateur.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299484/good-examples-of-database-questions-providing-some-sample-data-in-the-question

Answer (score 0):

As others stated in the comment, you should store the currency values in the proper data types. But for your requirement, you can use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) function to format the `totalprice` back to `varchar`. The `FORMAT` function formats the decimal into varchar with currency.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [UpdateOrderSentForBar]
@orderID   uniqueidentifier,
@tableNo varchar(255),
@currentprice decimal

AS
BEGIN

IF (SELECT orderStatus FROM tblOrders WHERE orderID=@orderID)='SentForKitchen'
BEGIN

IF (Select top 1 stallMessage From tblOrders WHERE tblNo = @tableNo AND orderStatus != 'Completed' AND orderID != @orderID) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
UPDATE tblOrders
SET stallMessage = stallMessage + (Select top 1 stallMessage From tblOrders WHERE tblNo = @tableNo AND orderStatus!='Completed' AND orderID !=@orderID), 
price = (FORMAT((CAST(REPLACE(price, '£', '') AS  DECIMAL(18,2)) + @currentprice), 'C', 'en-gb'))

WHERE orderID=@orderID
END
```